# How to set textview in a popup?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, popup, textview

I am trying to set the textview within a pop up and the string that is going into the textview PopUp is coming from a SOAP Web Service call.  I see the string message in my logCat and my PopUp pops but for some reason I just can't get set the textview to show my message.  What am I missing.

Thanks You.

```
    public void wtfPopUp()
    {

            //

            String PopYesNo;
            String PopMsgAll = null;
            //
////////////////////////FIRST CALL FOR YES-NO POP Status BEGIN
       SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACEPopYesNo, METHOD_NAMEPopYesNo);

          SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
          soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
          soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
          HttpTransportSE ahtt = new HttpTransportSE(URLPopYesNo);

          ////////////////////////  SECOND CALL FOR POP MESSAGE BEGIN

           SoapObject Request2 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACEAllPop, METHOD_NAMEAllPop);
           //   Request.addProperty("c_idid", "1");
              SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope2 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
              soapEnvelope2.dotNet = true;
              soapEnvelope2.setOutputSoapObject(Request2);
              HttpTransportSE ahtt2 = new HttpTransportSE(URLAllPop);

          ////////////////////////  SECOND CALL FOR MESSAGE END         

             try
             {
               Log.d("myAppWtf", "at getPopUpAllTRY");
             ahtt.call(SOAP_ACTIONPopYesNo, soapEnvelope);
            SoapObject oResponse = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
            PopYesNo = oResponse.getPropertyAsString(0).toString();
            Log.d("myAppYesNo", oResponse.getPropertyAsString(0).toString());       


                             if(PopYesNo.equals("PopUp_ON") )
                             {


                                                                try{

                                                                ////////////////////////  SECOND CALL FOR MESSAGE BEGIN

                                                                 ahtt2.call(SOAP_ACTIONAllPop, soapEnvelope2);
                                                                    SoapObject oResponse2 = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope2.bodyIn;
                                                                    PopMsgAll = oResponse2.getPropertyAsString(0).toString();
                                                                 Log.d("myAppMSGGGG", oResponse2.getPropertyAsString(0).toString());    

                                                                 /////////////////////////////  SECOND CALL FOR MESSAGE  END 

                                                                }
                                                                catch(Exception ms){

                                                                                  ms.printStackTrace();

                                                                }



                                                   // POP UP CODE
                                                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                                                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.popup_all, null);

                                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                                                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                                                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);



                                                // set dialog message
                                                alertDialogBuilder
                                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                                    .setNegativeButton("Cool",
                                                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                        }
                                                      });

                                                // create alert dialog
                                                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();




                                                // show it
                                                alertDialog.show();


                                                // TEXT FOR POP UP MSG
                                                 txtViewPop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMsgAll);
                                                 txtViewPop.setText(PopMsgAll.toString());
                                    //           txtViewPop.setTextColor(Color.rgb(2, 39, 72));



                             }


             }

             catch(Exception ix)
                 {
                     ix.printStackTrace();
                 }




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
txtViewPop =(TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.txtMsgAll);
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
txtViewPop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMsgAll);
```

Comment: Thank You!!!! Thank You!!!! Thank You!!!! Not sure what the it does but I will google for proper documentation.  Thank You.  SO is making me wait two min before I can mark the answer ???? Will do in two min.